# G Suite LDAP Search with ldapsearch

Tags: ldap, google-workspace

I've configured an ldap app in G Suite and I've downloaded the cert & key.  I'm trying to query it via ldapsearch:

```
LDAPTLS_CERT="Google_cert.crt" \
LDAPTLS_KEY="Google_cert.key" \
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.google.com:636 -b dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX -x '(mail=first.last@XXXXX.XXX)'
```

The response I get is this:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX> with scope subtree
# filter: (mail=first.last@XXXXX.XXX)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the response.  Did it execute the search and find nothing?  What do the `search`, `result`, and `numResponses` mean?

I would expect more information, as I'm searching for myself, so I know I'm in there.  Is my query messed up?

**EDIT**
Based on the comments, I changed my query to `*`:

```
LDAPTLS_CERT="Google_cert.crt" \
LDAPTLS_KEY="Google_cert.key" \
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.google.com:636 -b dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX -x '*'
```

and got this:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: *
#

# XXXXX.XXX
dn: dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
objectClass: dcObject
dc: XXXXX

# Groups, XXXXX.XXX
dn: ou=Groups,dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Groups

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 3
# numEntries: 2
```

Does this mean the only next level container is `Groups` and that next I need to search down in that ou?

Comment: `result: 0` : result code was zero, which is 'success' in the LDAP protocol. `numResponses`: the number of responses.

Comment: the search appears to have succeeded and returned nothing. This implies that you did connect to the LDAP service and that the  dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX exists. Try changing the '(mail=first.last@XXXXX.XXX)' to ('*')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm on a Mac, and `ldapsearch` on Mac is different.  Instead of using **LDAPTLS_CERT** & **LDAPTLS_KEY**, I had to convert the certificate and key files to one PKCS12 formatted file and import them into my MacBook's keychain, then use the **LDAPTLS_IDENTITY** environment variable with the ldapsearch command. This page [Connect LDAP clients to the Secure LDAP service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736?hl=en&ref_topic=9173976) has specific instructions for using ldapsearch on MacOS.

After that, this is the command that found my user:

```
LDAPTLS_IDENTITY="LDAP Client" ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.google.com:636 -b dc=XXXXX,dc=XXX '(uid=first.last)'
```

Hope this saves somebody else some time.

Comment: I get a `ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)` error when trying this command (after creating a .p12 as you suggested)

Comment: MY BAD. I didn't follow the instruction from Google properly and hadn't added my .p12 to the _SYSTEM_ Keychain. After doing that and specifically allowing /usr/bin/ldapsearch I can make queries